# Quick sort algorithm not working - giving wrong output

Tags: java, quicksort

I am learning algorithms like searching and sorting, and have written the quick sort algorithm. But for some reason, it is not giving the correct output. I looked thoroughly but was unable to solve it. Any help will be appreciated.

My code is below:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Quick_Sort {
    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    static void fill() {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter number :");
            a.add(s.nextInt());
        }
        
        a.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.print("\nBefore Sorting :");

        for (i = 0; i < a.size() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(a.get(i) + " ");
        }
    }


    static void swap(int i, int j) {
        int temp;

        temp = a.get(i);
        a.set(i, a.get(j));
        a.set(j, temp);
    }

    static int partition(int low, int high) {
        int i, j, pivot;

        i = low;
        j = high;

        pivot = a.get(low);
        do {
            do {
                i++;

            } while (i <= pivot);  //Finding larger element than pivot

            do {
                j--;

            } while (j > pivot); //Finding smaller element than pivot

            if (i < j) {
                swap(i, j);  // Swapping
            }

        } while (i < j);

        swap(low, j);    // Swapping the pivot into its correct position
        
        return j;
    }


    static void QuickS(int low, int high) {
        int p;

        System.out.println("low :" + low + " high :" + high);
        
        if (low < high) {
            p = partition(low, high);   //Finding the partion to divide the list

            System.out.println("mid :" + p);

            QuickS(low, p);
            QuickS(p + 1, high);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i;

        fill();
        QuickS(0, 4);          //Calling quick sort function

        System.out.print("\nAfter Sorting :");

        for (i = 0; i < a.size() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(a.get(i) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

End of the code here. Adding some random words so StackOverflow allows me to save this edit.

Comment: So, basically, you want to sort an array? What is your desired output?

Comment: Sorting the array in ascending order, thanks for asking , but recently I have found the error and solved. Thanks

Comment: @JeetNarayanChakraborty Then share the solution with us, please

Comment: *"But for some reason, it is not giving the correct output."* - please describe what's happening (and there would be no need to add random words). Show the input your code fails to sort, and the output it produces.

Comment: @ChristophS. I was comparing the index instead of the value at that index . That was the problem.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko , I gave input 6 1 7 2 , output was  1 7 2 6. I solved it , thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing pivot value to the index instead of the value in your array at the index.

`while (i <= pivot)` should be `while (a.get(i) <= pivot)`

`while (j > pivot)` should be `while (a.get(j) > pivot)`

Comment: I already solved , still Many Thanks.